# Touchpad not detected in Ubuntu 13.10 (Samsung Series 3 NP350V5C)

Tags: 13.10, touchpad, samsung

Touchpad is not detected at all:

```
>xinput list

⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ WebCam SC-13HDL11939N                     id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: You should [report this as a bug](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug). What the `synclient` command returns ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be fixed. I downloaded the synaptiks package from the Software Center and rebooted. Did the trick, no idea what the problem was.